# I joined a community to ask a question, and found it was the wrong community for me. How do I leave the community?

Tags: feature-request, support

I asked a Home network-type of question in the Network Experts community, and I was then informed that SuperUser was a better community to ask the question in, because Network Experts is for professionals (understood).  I deleted the question, and asked it in the right community, *but* given that I'm not a Network Professional, how do I leave that community?  I don't want their counts affected by a dead-weight user...

Comment: Incorrect -- I want to keep my account for all of my other communities (unless deleting your account *means* removing its association from one community while retaining others.)

Comment: Accounts are on a per-site basis. If you want to "leave a community" you need to delete your account on that site.

Comment: process described there works exactly as you want it to. It takes only accounts you want to delete (these where you put "please delete me" in the profile). Other accounts are kept

Comment: @Dan It's a dupe - you can choose to delete your account on only one community.

Comment: OK, it's a dupe, but it would be good that that distinction (or lack of it) be made clearer.  Not sure how, though, but a GREAT place to start would be an FAQ (where I searched first before asking the question here).  I have no problem having this question deleted, *but* leaving it here, although it is technically a dupe, it isn't, because my question is exactly what I searched for, and *didn't* find my answer.

Comment: ...and thanks, I got my answer from the question this is the duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one option: to delete you account.

When you have made an account on that site, the only way to be no longer associated with it is to delete your account for that site (don't delete your entire account...). This is the easiest way to no longer be part of that site. If you want an alternate, try the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page (I have no clue if there are any at all by the way).